# how to play online video using uri with .mov formate in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming

- I want to play video on android phone using video URL with .mov format but not able to play video in videoview
- i use this library
  click here https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView

> Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("https://***");
>
> ```
>    try {
>         videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are trying to play the video, and explain **in detail** what problems you are encountering.

Comment: @Jay Patel..... Please check android Supported Media Formats using below link, https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Comment: @ janak thanks, I already refer that doc but  is there no way to play that video??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got one media player which is develop by google and support all type of video and audio formate include youtube url and support **http://** and **https://** type url
here is link
https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/